# Mail function is not working

Tags: php

I am using php mail function.

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
  //if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
   //send email
   $text=$_REQUEST['text'];
   $enquiry=$_REQUEST['mail-subject'];
   $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
   $departure = $_REQUEST['departure'];
   $subject=$_REQUEST['subject'];
   $mmimessage=$_REQUEST['message'];
   $message = '<html><body>';
   $message.='name:'.$text."<br/>".'Email:'.$email."<br/>".'Department:'.$departure."<br/>".'Subject:'.$subject."<br/>".'Message:'.$mmimessage."<br/>".$_REQUEST['mmimessage'];
   $message .= '</body></html>';
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
   $check= mail("ndhivyamani@gmail.com",$text,$message,$headers);
  }
?>

<form action="" method="POST" name="contact-us" id="contact-us">
    <div class="col-md-6 margin-bottom-40">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name*" name="text" id="text" class="form-control" required>         
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 margin-bottom-40">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email *" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required>               
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 margin-bottom-40">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Department*" name="departure" id="departure" class="form-control" required>              
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 margin-bottom-40">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject *" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-40">                   
        <textarea placeholder="Tell us more about you and how MMI can assist you in your export/import needs" rows="8" class="form-control"   name="message" id="message" > </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 margin-bottom-40" style="text-align:center">                   
         <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit">
    </div>  
</form>
```

This mail function is not working in windows server.It shows the error like this

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in
>   php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   D:\HostingSpace\mmiexim.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 324

Answer (score 0):

Windows machines do not have the capability to send email on their own: while many Linux distributions come with a program that can send mail (usually called 'sendmail'), Windows doesn't, which means that PHP on Windows has to communicate with a mail server (MTA) to send email.

You should do as the error message says and configure a mail server. You could try to set one up yourself, or use your ISP's, Gmail's, or one from a dedicated email sending service like Amazon SES, Mandrill, Sendgrid or Postmark.

Note that the stock mail function does not support authentication. If you decide to use a mail server that needs authentication (most do), you will need to use something like SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your error message clearly states that there is an error in your php.ini settings to send the mail. Please set your SMTP configuration correctly in the php.ini file.

Comment: where should i put my php.ini file?@Sourabh

Comment: @user3122556, you do not have to put it any where, you already have it in your php directory, you just need to configure it correctly.